# What's the difference between Audience Builder and Audience Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, audience-builder, audiencestudio

I see both regularly in articles and help guides. I use Audience Builder regularly but haven't seen anything called Audience Studio within Marketing Cloud. Are these the same thing? Or is Audience Studio a different product not currently in my suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audience Studio (AS) is a completely separate product. I believe it used to be called SFMC DMP. It allows you to ingest a ton of data from locations outside of SFMC and create audiences and segmentations for smarter marketing based off of that. These audiences are then used in Journey Builder, Email Sends, etc.

Audience Studio though is being outshone lately with the rise of Interaction Studio(IS). IS seems to be a much more robust and capable tool than AS ever was. Here is a **[link](https://www.trustradius.com/compare-products/salesforce-audience-studio-vs-salesforce-marketing-cloud-interaction-studio)** comparing the two. IS used to be Evergage before SF bought them.

Although both are fairly expensive, I have found many more feel positive about Interaction Studio than Audience Studio. Most people I know that use AS wish they could transition off of it due to the cost and the many 'quirks' that happen with it.

That being said, depending on your context, use case and budget, both are viable options to choose from (or not choose).

Audience Builder is the 'section' inside SFMC that houses Contact Builder, Audience Studio, and other similar data oriented applications - similar to how 'Journey Builder' section houses both Automation Studio and Journey Builder application.

Comment: Actually [Audience Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ab_audience_builder.htm&type=5) is a tool within Marketing Cloud, which allows for drag & drop segmentation on large data sets. It utilises an external non-relational DB to build segments much easier and faster than using SQL/Data Filters in SFMC. I do admit, that the naming of the tab in the MC top menu, is a bit confusing... AB will probably be replaced with [360 Audiences](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customer360_a.htm&type=5), which is the latest offering from Salesforce to be used for segmentation.

Comment: Crap did I switch the names? I will adjust it when I get to a computer

Comment: Both the tab AND the tool are both called "Audience Builder" - so you are not incorrect. But from a feature perspective, Audience Builder is the segmentation tool, as described in my comment.